# Does the one-handed perk "Savage Strike" give you a bonus when dual-wielding?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just wanted to know if the bonuses translated to dual-wielding as well, or is it pointless to even get if you aren't going to only use one weapon at a time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The perks that do not apply specifically to dual wielding apply to attacks made with two (2) one-handed weapons, one (1) one-handed weapon and/or one (1) one-handed weapon and one (1) shield. The dual wielding perks give those fighting with two weapons additional bonuses to compensate for the lack of defensive shields/magic. Two weapon fighting is all out offense and receives all of the benefits from the other perks found in the one-handed tree.

The only "exception" to this might be Critical Charge as I seem to attack with only one of the two weapons I have equipped. It gives you a nice movement and damage bonus though, so I still think it is worth taking as a two weapon fighter.

Side note: I highly recommend taking this perk because the decapitate animation is both cool and satisfying.

Comment: Thanks. More explanation than I needed, but I genuinely appreciate that. Didn't want to waste a perk if it didn't actually do anything when dual wielding. Glad I can now have a 75% or more bonus to my power attacks, or what I call "rushes."

Comment: More supplementary information: I haven't officially tested this but it feels like dual wielding with 1 dagger and 1 (any other weapon) gives you the power attack speed of the dagger. There is a noticeable differnece in attack speeds between daggers and maces (daggers being much faster).